# Install ubuntu with the command line

Tags: command-line, system-installation, filesystem, live-cd, squashfs

I want to install Ubuntu without using Ubiquity. I want to install it through the command line only. Not looking for Ubuntu Server install. Just help on how I can  install it through the command line.

I know in Arch Linux you can use `pacstrap base` to install a basic system. Is there any way I can manually extract the file system from the LiveCD?

Comment: Why not server install?

Comment: You can use `debootstrap` for a similar purpose, but it isn't available by default in any of the Ubuntu ISOs.

Comment: So, how can I use debootstrap to copy the filesystem from my ISO to the new filesystem?

Comment: Or, install a very basic system.

Comment: Well, first either you'd have to customize the ISO before preparing bootable media, or have internet available while installation. Which will it be?

Comment: Customize the ISO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu does have Minimal CDs that are 35MB - 40MB in size that install the base system and allow you to do command line installation. They also let you choose only the packages that you want to install.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD